# How can you alter JavaScript in the browser and then run it with the modifications?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser

I'm trying to compile a list of all the links that are possible between two `<select></select>` boxes. This includes both links that open in a new window and redirections that happen to the current page. There are many more options on the actual site, almost 2000 possibilites, so doing it manually is out of the question...

Anywhere close to this output is what I'm looking for, not the formatting, just the data:

product1 + AL:

- New Window: /product1.asp
- Redirect: NONE

product1 + AK:

- New Window: http://affiliate.com/product1.asp
- Redirect: /results.asp?st=AK&pr=product1

product1 + AR:

- New Window: http://affiliate.com/product1.asp
- Redirect: /results.asp?st=AR&pr=product1

product2 + AL:

- ...

product2 + AK:

- ...

Etc.

I would have used cURL but the form doesn't really submit anywhere, it only uses JS to open new windows and/or redirect the current page.

Here's a small sample of what I'm trying to work with:

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
            function submit()
            {
                if (product == "product1"){
                    if (state == "AL"){
                        openWindow('/product1.asp');
                    }
                    else{
                        openWindow('http://affiliate.com/product1.asp');
                        return(window.location="/results.asp?st=" + state + "&pr=product1");
                    }
                }
                if (product == "product2"){
                    openWindow('/product2.asp');
                }
                if (product == "product3"){
                    if (state == "AR") { 
                        openWindow('http://affiliate.com/product3.asp'); 
                    }
                    else{
                        openWindow('/product3'); 
                        return (window.location = "/results.asp?st=" + state + "&pr=product3"); 
                    }
                }
                return(true);
            }

            function openWindow(url)
            {
              window.open(url, '', 'type=fullwindow,fullscreen,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=1,menubar=1');
            }
        </script>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <form onsubmit="" action="javascript:submit()" method="post" id="form1" name="form1">
            <select name="state" tabindex="1">
                <option value="">Select</option>
                <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
            </select>

            <select name="productType" tabindex="2">
                <option value="">Select</option>
                <option value="product1">Product One</option>
                <option value="product2">Product Two</option>
                <option value="product3">Product Three</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

I figured I could use JavaScript in Chrome's console window, but I cannot for the life of me get Chrome to stop the redirection, or opening of another window.

I've tried selecting all of the HTML on the page, running a string replace (with JS) to replace `window.location` with a variable name so that `window.location = "/results.asp"` becomes `redirectLink = "/results.asp"` and then re-writing HTML back into the document, and then calling `submit()` and it kind of works, it can get the URL, but then Chrome still uses the original JS redirection and I can't access or see the data. I've even tried opening a new window and writing the entire page's HTML with the replacements there, but nothing...

This is the JS code I have to replace it:

```
var script = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
var html = scripts[i].innerHTML;
html = html.replace(/window.location/gmi, "redirectLink"); // the "/string/gmi" is to replace globally, on multi-lines, and ignores case
script.innerHTML = html;
```

In Chrome's Inspect Element tool, it **DOES** show that the replacements have been made and everything, but when calling `submit()` it still redirects/opens windows... I have loops setup to change the selected values and all that other stuff, which all work, but I can't stop it from using doing the original JS redirection/new window crap...

I've literally been trying to get this to work for 5 hours straight and I'm going to go bald from pull all my hair out at this point!

Is it even possible to alter JavaScript in a browser and then run it with the modifications?  Is there a better way to go about this? I'm at a complete loss for ideas...

Answer (score 0):

You will have to find a plugin for that